# How to detect brute force in mod-security

Tags: firewall, hacking, mod-security

I checked the core rules set in the mod-security but it's didn't contain the rules related to Brute-Force Attack!!! Did anyone know how to write the rules or the existing rules for this kind of Attack!

Thanks in advanced,

Answer (score 1):

It's a better idea to have some daemon monitoring the logs and taking action. Fail2Ban works wonders for me. Alternatives exist.

Answer (score 0):

Check is post: http://www.dongit.nl/tech/modsecurity-brute-force-protection

Comment: Link-and-run answers are discouraged here on ServerFault. It is polite to include at least a summary of what the article contains, even if it is just the very broad steps. If they need detail, they can click.